# Fastest character replacement in string

Tags: php, performance, string

I need to replace a char in a string.

```
$s1='123456789';
$s2='abcdefghi';

$p=4; // position of char in $s1 to use for replacing (0 is first char)

$s2 = ???? ; // code
```

In the end $s2 must be 'abcd5fghi'

What would be fastest method?

Comment: Are you sure you need certainly fastest method? Just fast enough wouldn't suit you?

Comment: Looking at the answers the fastest way is sometimes the best way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only have single-byte characters:

```
$s2[$p] = $s1[$p];
```

Otherwise, in case of multi-byte characters, you will probably need to use [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/mb_substr):

```
$s2 = mb_substr($s2, 0, $p).mb_substr($s1, $p, 1).mb_substr($s2, $p+1);
```

Comment: I learn something new. Thanks for saving me time writing the crap long version.

Answer (score 3):

[String access and modification by character](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr)

```
$s2[$p] = $s1[$p];
```